# When submitting the app where do I declare the In-App Purchases?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, in-app-purchase, windows-phone-8.1

The guide says that I need to declare the in app purchases (token, price, availability) in the submission process, but I can't for the life of me find it!

If it's a universal app, do I need to resubmit the Windows Store app (versus the Windows Phone app which is submitted separately) and put the In-App Purchases in there?

Does that mean that both Phone and Non-Phone apps have to have the same list of in-app purchases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows Store dashboard, populating your list of in-app purchases is done from the Selling Details section early in the submission process. There's a link there near the top of the page, under "In-app Purchases" that says "Use the Windows Store in-app purchase system." This takes you to the page where you enter the purchase details.

In the Windows Phone Store dashboard, once you've created an app, go back to the dashboard home, click on the app under In-progress Submissions, and you'll see a page with a number of links/tabs: Lifecycle | Quick stats | Reviews | Pricing | Details | Products. Click on "Products" and you'll go to the place where you define in-app purchases.

You do need to create the in-app purchases separately on both dashboards, because you are submitting separate apps in the end. Each submission can therefore have its own list of in-app purchases, because clearly there are scenarios where you might have a purchase available on one platform but not the other.

Now if you have the apps in both stores associated with one another, i.e. you use the same app name and then associate them so they have the same package family name/ID, then you allow your customers to share in-app purchases between the two apps, *provided* that you use the same product ID for each. This way, the app ID + product ID uniquely identifies the in-app purchase for the user, so if the user has purchased it on one platform it's available on the other. If you use different product IDs, however, then you won't have that shared entitlement.

Note that it's the app ID + product ID that makes these shared entitlements: you can implement each app however you want, meaning that you don't have to use an universal app project. They must both be targeting the 8.1 platforms, however, because that's where this capability is enabled.